# Jquery animate blur function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, blur

I am using a jquery blur plugin called "Vague.js". It allows me to blur anything on a website. Now I want to animate the blurring. How do I call the .blur() function from a jquery animate() ?

```
//This sets up the plugin and applies the blur to my content

var contentblur = $('#content').Vague({intensity:5});
contentblur.blur();
```

I want to do something like:

```
contentblur.animate(blur,500);
```

https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/vague.js

Answer (score 1):

You can make the blur animated only on browser which support `filter` property and transitions.

It's easy as setting transition on that element

```
#content {
   transition: all 1s;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

You can see the jsfiddle demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/vmWs3/